# How to make struct point to previous array value

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, struct

My `schedule->start.hour` points to the currect element of array. How to make it point to the previous element of array?

```
struct Time {
  int hour;
} start, end;

struct Class {
  struct Time start, end;
} schedule[100];
```

I need to use this inside a function which sets start of current to be equal to end of previous.

```
void add_class(struct Class shedule[]){
    schedule->start.hour=schedule*(--).end.hour;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need something like the following

```
void add_class( struct Class shedule[], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        shedule[i].start.hour = shedule[i-1].end.hour;
    }

    //... 
}
```

and the function is called like

```
add_class( shedule, sizeof( shedule ) / sizeof( *shedule ) );
```

or like

```
add_class( shedule, 100 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not really clear what you are after and the code you show is wrong. There are no pointers there at all.

If you want to access different instances of Class in the schedule array you need

```
  schedule[0].start.hour;
  schedule[1].start.hour;
  ....
```

to loop over them all

```
  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
      printf("start=%d, end = %d\n",schedule[i].start.hour, scehdule[i].end.hour);
  }
```

if you have a pointer to a Class instance

```
void add_class(struct Class shedule[]){
         ...
};
```

You can access the prior entry in the array like this

```
 void add_class(struct Class schedule[]){
       struct Class *prior = schedule - 1;
       schedule->start.hour=prior->end.hour;
};
```

But , and this is a huge but, this will be very bad if this is the first element in the array.

I would still do it by passing indexes tho.

Comment: I don't know index of element

Comment: @devec - that doesnt make sense. Either you are walking through the array or you are accessing specific ones., the code you showed `schedule->start.hour` is the same as `schedule[0].start.hour`, which one do you want now, you cannot get the 'prior' one as there isnt one

Comment: I edited question to add more details

Comment: could you edit your answer? I need to use that in a function where I don't know which index will appear

Comment: @devec , see edit

Comment: I set a condition which which ensures that the element cannot be the first